# Port forward to one of multiple devices depending on which one is connected?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm running **FreshTomato Firmware 2020.2 K26ARM USB AIO-64K** but this question is generally about "advanced use cases" of port forwarding.

Is it possible to set up router policies so that traffic coming in on a specific port on the WAN is forwarded to one of multiple (two in my case) devices (IP addresses), depending on which one is currently connected to the router (is not turned off)?

To give a concrete example, let's say I have a **PS3** (192.168.1.**3**) and a **PS4** (192.168.1.**4**).
PSN sends traffic on ports 3478-3480. I'm expecting an inbound connection to be established on these ports so I want to set up a rule:

- If PS3 is connected and traffic is received on [WAN_IP]:**3478**, route packets to 192.168.1.**3:3478**
- If PS4 is connected ..., route packets to 192.168.1.**4:3478**
- ditto for ports 3479,3480 and whatever arbitrary set of ports I define
- If both PS3 and PS4 are connected, then **fallback** on routing it to PS4

I would find it hard to believe that this kind of routing logic can't be implemented.

And yes, I know that typically there has to be a many-to-one mapping between incoming connections on the WAN port to LAN device port, and I want something like a many-to-multiple mapping which is dependent on checking certain conditions and route accordingly with a fallback route. Think of it as a "switch statement" for routing.
I'm simply looking for a way to **practically solve my specific problem** with routing (***doesn't necessarily have to be port forwarding***).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what load balancers (HAproxy, nginx) or Linux Virtual Server do.

You configure multiple targets for a service and a health check (application level check or just a TCP connection opening). Depending on which targets are currently reachable, incoming connections are forwarded to just one or several ones.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking of!
I have experience working on HAproxy and nginx so I'll see if I can integrate it and have it run on FreshTomato.